# How to print the output to same file you are reading from in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which reads a file, changes the required thing and then prints the output of the file on the console. 
I want the output to be updated in the same file from where it is picking the data.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can do it as follows: 1. open file, 2. read whole file into variable, 3. close file, 4. manipulate data in variable, 5. open file (same), 6. write content of variable into the file, 7. close the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-i` switch, or the `$^I` special variable.

```
perl -i.backup -pe 's/change me/something else/'
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$^I = '.backup';
while (<>) {
    ...
    print;
}
```

Note that it only works for the special file handle `*ARGV` used by the diamond operator. It creates a new file behind the scenes, anyway.

See [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) and [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar).

Comment: You can also use [edit_lines(_utf8) from Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#edit_lines,-edit_lines_utf8,-edit_lines_raw) to do a similar operation programmatically in a full script.